# Angular-oauth2-oidc throws error when trying to refresh token

Tags: oauth-2.0, angular-oauth2-oidc

When the token expires and the refresh flow triggers I get the following error:

error: "invalid_grant"
​​
error_description: "MSIS9630: The refresh token received in 'refresh_token' parameter is invalid. The device identifier in the token does not match the specified device certificate."

The error only occurs on firefox, on chrome it works with no problems.
Does anyone know what this error means?

I`m using "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1" with angular 15.2.10

I tried updating the version of the oauth library but I still get the error only on firefox.

Comment: Ooh, that sounds like a nasty problem to encounter! From a distance it looks to me like more of a specific interaction between the browser and your specific IDS, than something particular to the `angular-oauth2-oidc` library. Either way, we don't have enough details or a way to reproduce the issue, so it's pretty hard to provide external help. Please consider sharing steps to set up a minimal repro, the code it involves, and the settings for your IDS and browser so the community could help find an answer?